# How do I rationalize the equation $\frac{3-x}{1- \sqrt{x-2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I rationalize this equation
$$\frac{3-x}{1- \sqrt{x-2}} ? $$

Comment: Since you're new, I'd like to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are**. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: The collection of symbols
$$\frac{3-x}{1- \sqrt{x-2}}$$
is an **expression**, not an equation (note the lack of an equals sign).

Comment: last note  to @One With The Basic Que,if some answer  is usefully and helpful  for you,just accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{3-x}{1-\sqrt{x-2}}=\frac{3-x}{1-\sqrt{x-2}}\frac{1+\sqrt{x-2}}{1+\sqrt{x-2}}=\frac{(3-x)(1+\sqrt{x-2})}{1-(x-2)}=$$

$$=\frac{(3-x)(1+\sqrt{x-2})}{3-x}=1+\sqrt{x-2}$$